# Evaluating $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2 - \sqrt{3 + \sqrt{4 - \cdots}}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, nested-radicals

> $$x =\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2 - \sqrt{3 + \sqrt{4 - \sqrt{5+ \sqrt{6 - \cdots}}}}}}$$
>
> Find $x$.

I am not sure how to proceed.

Is this a sort of Arithmetico-Geometric Progression? Will this converge at a point?

Any help would be sincerely appreciated.

---

Comment: I don't know how to answer this question, but see if [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical#Ramanujan's_infinite_radicals) can help.

Comment: Empirical attempt: plot the functions: $f_n(t)=\sqrt{t+\sqrt{t+1-\sqrt{t+2+\sqrt{t-3-\sqrt{t+4\dots+(-1)^{n+1} \sqrt{t+n}}}}}}$ with more and more nesting. It appears they converge to an $f$. But it also appears that $f$ is defined only for $t$ greater than a $t_0$ which itself is $\gt 1$. The asked question is "does $f(1)$ exist and if yes what's its value?". I expect from that graphical evidence that the anwer should be no.

Comment: Since the same thing with all + signs has no known closed form, why should this?  See https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NestedRadicalConstant.html  There still remains the problem to prove (or disprove) convergence.

Comment: The computations will involve complex numbers.  Starting at stage $4$.  So $$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3+\sqrt{4}}}} \approx 1.03 + i\;0.24$$  Always choosing the "principal" square root, the limit seems to be $1.005667607 + i\;0.1066177058$

Comment: @GEdgar Isn't that the only point where complex numbers show up? $\sqrt{5}\lt 4$, $\sqrt{5+\sqrt{6}}\lt 4$, and that gap is only going to grow wider. So there's only square root taken in the process that can be complex, the one at $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3+\ldots}}$.

Comment: Doing this from $a=\sqrt{3+\sqrt{4-\sqrt{...}}}$ we get $a \approx 2.045986206239776$. Of course proceeding $b=\sqrt{2-a}$ is complex and then also $c=\sqrt{1+b}$. I got the same final solution as @GEdgar as about $c \approx 1.005668 + i 0.106618$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I doubt a closed form exists for this number, but I'll show convergence and give some bounds on the values.

Let $f_m^n = \sqrt{m\pm\sqrt{(m+1)\mp \sqrt{\cdots\pm \sqrt n}}} $
be the the version where we go from $m$ to $n$ (don't take the $\pm$'s too seriously). We have the recursive expression
$$
f_m^n = \begin{cases}
\sqrt{m + (-1)^{m+1}f_{m+1}^n} & m<n \\
\sqrt n & m=n
\end{cases}
$$

**Realness and general bounds:**

Let $3 \le m < n$ with $n$ large enough. I claim that
$$
f_m^n - \sqrt{m-1} \in \begin{cases}
[0.5, 0.7] & m \textrm{ odd} \\
[-0.4, -0.6] & m \textrm{ even}
\end{cases}
$$
These constants can surely be refined, and maybe the ranges can be made to depend on $m$ as well to sharpen it further. Furthermore, it shouldn't be hard to show that $f_m^\infty-\sqrt m \to \pm \frac12$ for $m\to \infty$.

In particular everything is real in these cases (which is easy to check). We can show it by backwards induction on $m$. You can check that the base case $m=n-1$ holds for $n\ge8$.

For $m<n-1$ we must check for odd $m$ that
$$
f_m^n \in \left[ \sqrt{m + \sqrt{m} - 0.4}, \sqrt{m + \sqrt{m} - 0.6} \right]
\subset \left[ \sqrt{m-1} + 0.5, \sqrt{m-1} + 0.7 \right]
$$
and for even $m$ that
$$
f_m^n\in \left[ \sqrt{m - \sqrt{m} - 0.7}, \sqrt{m - \sqrt{m} - 0.5} \right]
\subset \left[ \sqrt{m-1} - 0.6, \sqrt{m-1} - 0.4 \right]
$$
These are quadratic inequalities, so we can run the numbers and see that they all hold for $m\ge3$.

**Bounds on $f_1$:**

Assume for now that $f_m^n$ converges as $n\to\infty$, which I'll prove below. Then the same bounds as above hold for $f_m := \lim_{n\to\infty}f_m^n$. Let's get some better bounds on $f_3$. We have
$$
f_3 = \sqrt{3+\sqrt{4-f_5}}
\in \left[\sqrt{3+\sqrt{4-\sqrt{4}-0.7}}, \sqrt{3+\sqrt{4-\sqrt{4}-0.5}}\right]
\approx [2.035, 2.055]
$$
We could get increasingly better bounds by using a higher term than $f_5$. Assuming the principal squareroot for complex numbers, we get approximately
$$
f_2 = \sqrt{2-f_3}
\in [0.186i, 0.235i]
$$
This finally gives us bounds on $f_1$. If $f_1=x+iy$, then $f_1$ lies on the curve $x^2-y^2=1$ and between the values approximately $1.00430 + 0.0928i$ and $1.00681 + 0.117i$.

**Convergence:**

We want to use that
$$
\lvert \sqrt{a+x} - \sqrt a \rvert \le \frac{|x|}{2}
$$
or
$$
\sqrt{a+x} = \sqrt a + \varepsilon\left(\frac{|x|}{2}\right)
$$
where $\varepsilon(x)$ means some number that is smaller than $x$ in absolute value.

This holds for all $x$ as long as $a\ge4$. We only need to show convergence for one value of $m$, so choose $m_0$ large enough that $(f_m^n)^2 \ge 4$ for all $n \ge m \ge m_0$ (we can do this using the bounds above). We unravel the radical from the inside out and get inductively (with the base case $k=0$ evident):
$$ \begin{split}
f_{n-k}^n 
&= \sqrt{(n-k) \pm f_{n-k+1}^{n}} \\
&= \sqrt{(n-k) \pm f_{n-k+1}^{n-1} + \varepsilon\left(\frac{\sqrt n}{2^{k-1}}\right)} \\
&= \sqrt{\left(f_{n-k}^{n-1}\right)^2 + \varepsilon\left(\frac{\sqrt n}{2^{k-1}}\right)} \\
&= f_{n-k}^{n-1} + \varepsilon\left(\frac{\sqrt n}{2^{k}}\right) \\
\end{split}
$$
In particular
$$
f_{m_0}^n = f_{m_0}^{n-1} + \varepsilon\left(\frac{\sqrt n}{2^{n-m_0}}\right)
$$
which means that
$$
f_{m_0} = \sum_{n=m_0}^\infty \varepsilon\left(\frac{\sqrt n}{2^{n-m_0}}\right)
$$
which is absolutely convergent.

Comment: Very well explained, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Milten.- You are an artist.

Answer (score 2):

This is just an empirical answer. Consider

$$f(n) = \sqrt{t+\sqrt{t+1 - \sqrt{t+2 + \sqrt{t+3 - \cdots}}}}$$

We need to find $f(1)$. But

\begin{align}
f(1) &= \sqrt{1+\sqrt{2 - f(3)}}\\
f(3) &= \sqrt{3+\sqrt{4 - f(5)}}\tag{Similarly moving on }\\
f(n) &= \sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+1 - f(n+2)}}\\
\end{align}

After squaring and rearranging, we get

$$f(n+2) = n+1 - (f(n)^2 - n)^2$$

I used the [wolfram alpha recurrence solver](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=g%28n%2B2%29%3Dn%2B1+-+%28g%28n%29%5E2+-+n%29%5E2) to solve the recurrence and it gave me this:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
n& 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
 g(n) & 0  & 1 & 1 & 2& 2\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

I don't know if this helps, but $x = 1$.

Comment: This doesn't seem very fruitful. Clearly $f(1)$ is not $1$ (which you seem to claim at the end?). Any two initial values will generate a sequence satisfying the recurrence, so we haven't really learned anything.

Comment: @Milten, Agreed.

Comment: @Vinanth S Bharadwaj , your recurring equation is not correct, check the function well, you didn't account for the even number and yet you put it on the table

Answer (score 1):

The computations will involve complex numbers. Starting at stage $4$. So
$$
\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3+\sqrt{4}}}} \approx 1.03 + i\;0.24
$$
Always choosing the "principal" square root, the limit seems to be  $1.005667607+ i\; 0.1066177058$ .

**added**
In fact, $\sqrt{3+\dots}$ converges to a real value, but $\sqrt{2-\dots}$  and $\sqrt{1+\dots}$ to non-real values.

Comment: I’m not convinced by that. Because after 4, you have $-\sqrt{5+...}$. Then, not sure we need complex numbers here.

Comment: @GEdgar do you have an error-bar for that approximation of the limit? I've just randomly found that this seems to be very close to $\sqrt{1+i/\delta}$. This would be either a coincidence, or it would mean that some form of chaotic map is involved here (which in fact wouldn't be so surprising here)

Answer (score -1):

$$x = \sqrt{1+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3+\sqrt{4-\cdots }}}} $$
If I put write the recurring equation of this statement
$f[n] = \sqrt{n-(-1)^{n}\cdot f[n+1] }$
But the value of $x$ is a complex number so recurring equation can't reveal much, But instead if we mirror $x$, by a change of sign from $+ $ to $ - $

We get it's conjugate
$$ y = -\sqrt{1-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3-\sqrt{4+\cdots }}}} $$
$y$ is also a complex number, but conjugate to $x$
$x$ and $y$ can therefore appear as the roots of some quadratic, so that $x + y $ and $ x \cdot y $ are real

What remains is to reduce the identities